# Url Parameter Passing

Tags: php, url-parameters

My project based on php i am using htaccess to hide .php and also added trailing slashes at the end of file name my htaccess file containg following rule

```
Options +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
# Forces a trailing slash to be added
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

# disable directory browsing
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.+?\ [^?]+\.php[?\ ]
RewriteRule \.php$ - [F]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.+?\ [^?]+\.html[?\ ]
RewriteRule \.html$ - [F]
```

My URL is like the following

```
http://www.example.com/example/
```

Now I have to pass the parameter value 10 with the above link by:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/example?10/"></a>
```

but my page shows object not found i have created example.php file but the parameter not passing and getting the page example.php please help me how to  pass the parameter value 10 to my example.php file with above htaccess file conditions and also explain how to get those parameter value 10 from example.php file

Comment: http://www.example.com/example/?10 seems like the only way it would work to me.

Comment: <a href="http://www.example.com/example?par=10/"></a> pass it like this.

Comment: it doesn't work if i am passing <a href="example.com/example?par=10/"></a>; it returns the same page itself it doesn't bring the next page

Comment: it will add extra domain url like this in address bar http://www.example.com/www.example.com/example?par=10/ i have to move from one page to example page by href with parameter also